# In the sentence 'he was very early', would it be correct to say that 'early' functions as both a noun and the object of the sentence?

Tags: adjectives, sentences

I'm currently trying to construct my own language as an exercise, and I need to know if such a description is linguistically accurate, or if the word should be described otherwise.

Comment: Oh, I was reading something close to this but I don't remember what it was.

Comment: No, _early_ is neither an object nor a noun in that sentence. It’s an adjective that functions as predicative complement over the subject, more commonly called a subject complement.